# Rocky 9.1 dracut fails to boot

Tags: lvm, luks, initramfs, rocky-linux, dracut

My rocky 9.1 vm kernel is not able to load/boot/decrypt a LVM Luks2 volume during boot.
Booting with 5.14.0-162.6 works fine. But fails booting the latest 5.14.0-162.18 or 5.14.0-162.12 kernel, dracut throws with error:

```
Starting dracut pre-udev hook.
dracut-pre-udev[397] modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'dm_mod': Operation not permitted.
```

/run/iniramfs/rdsosreport.txt

```
dmsetup ls --tree
/dev/mapper/control: open failed: No such device
Failure to communicate with kernel device-mapper driver.
Check that device-mapper is available in the kernel.
Incompatible libdevmapper 1.02.185 (2022-05-18) and kernel driver (unknown version).
Command failed.
```

I've created a new initramfs. Grub settings and modules are identical.

lsinitrd -m  initramfs-5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1.0.1.x86_64.img

```
Image: initramfs-5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1.0.1.x86_64.img: 33M
========================================================================
Version: dracut-057-13.git20220816.el9

dracut modules:
bash
systemd
systemd-initrd
systemd-sysusers
dbus-broker
dbus
i18n
network-manager
network
ifcfg
prefixdevname
crypt
dm
kernel-modules
kernel-modules-extra
kernel-network-modules
lvm
qemu
qemu-net
resume
rootfs-block
terminfo
udev-rules
virtiofs
biosdevname
dracut-systemd
usrmount
base
fs-lib
memstrack
microcode_ctl-fw_dir_override
shutdown
```

lsinitrd -m  initramfs-5.14.0-162.18.1.el9_1.x86_64.img

```
Image: initramfs-5.14.0-162.18.1.el9_1.x86_64.img: 33M
========================================================================
Version: dracut-057-13.git20220816.el9

dracut modules:
bash
systemd
systemd-initrd
systemd-sysusers
nss-softokn
dbus-broker
rngd
dbus
i18n
network-manager
network
ifcfg
prefixdevname
crypt
dm
kernel-modules
kernel-modules-extra
kernel-network-modules
lvm
qemu
qemu-net
resume
rootfs-block
terminfo
udev-rules
virtiofs
biosdevname
dracut-systemd
usrmount
base
fs-lib
memstrack
microcode_ctl-fw_dir_override
shutdown
```

Packages are all up to date. I've reinstall the kernel, kernel-modules and lvm2 without success.

I've managed to rebuild a rescue initramfs and vmlinuz through a live CD chroot by executing /usr/lib/kernel/install.d/51-dracut-rescue.install.
The rescue system is booting the 5.14.0-162.18 kernel.
But a lot modules are missing.

```
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
fuse                  176128  1
drm                   622592  0
ext4                  962560  3
mbcache                16384  1 ext4
jbd2                  167936  1 ext4
dm_crypt               61440  2
sr_mod                 28672  0
cdrom                  81920  1 sr_mod
sg                     40960  0
ata_generic            16384  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ata_piix               45056  0
crc32c_intel           24576  6
virtio_net             65536  0
libata                389120  2 ata_piix,ata_generic
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
serio_raw              20480  0
net_failover           24576  1 virtio_net
virtio_blk             20480  4
failover               16384  1 net_failover
dm_mirror              28672  0
dm_region_hash         24576  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 20480  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
dm_mod                184320  17 dm_crypt,dm_log,dm_mirror
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Could you try to disable secure boot? If it's working see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/543580/1254

Comment: Nope, that did not work. But I've managed to rebuild a rescue initramfs and vmlinuz from a live CD. Booting the rescue kernel 5.14.0-162.18.1 is now working, but a lot of modules are not loaded.

Comment: I've ended up reinstalling the system. Guess it caused form a corrupt rocky 8 to 9 upgrade.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error (`ERROR: could not insert 'dm_mod': Operation not permitted.`) after upgrading from 5.14.0-162.12.1.el9_1.0.2 to 5.14.0-162.23.1.el9_1. Disks are LVM but not encrypted, and this was a fresh Rocky 9 install. I'm using SeaBIOS instead of UEFI, so no Secure boot involved apparently.

Comment: Have you solved it? I've faced the same issue again after the reinstall and now on an upgrade from kernel 5.14.0-284.11.1 to 5.14.0-284.18.1. The reinstall was not encrypted too.

Comment: might be related to https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5160421 I see the same on Oracle Linux with 5.15.0-103 while -101 works. I rebuild the initrd. Odd bug or foul play by RH? I don't have access to the bugzilla, but it sounds way too similar and the date is also very close.

Answer (score 0):

This worked after all for me after doing some research and regenerating the `initramfs` from the previous kernel version:

```
cd /boot
dracut -f initramfs-5.14.0-162.23.1.el9_1.x86_64.img 5.14.0-162.23.1.el9_1.x86_64
reboot
```

Booted nicely on 5.14.0-162.23.1.el9_1.x86_64 version …